# Am I being throttled by my ISP?

Tags: networking, bittorrent, isp, throttling

Everything is slow, it seems that a have a limit for each host where I connect. For example when I use BitTorrent, each peer is limited to no exceed **30 kB/s**. So if I'm connected to **10 peers** I get **300kB/s**... and that's cool! because this speed is even faster that the speed that I requested. But it's not cool when I go to Youtube and try to watch a video at **30kB/s**.

Am I being throttled by my ISP? If it does, what can I exactly say when I call to support?

Comment: [See this page](http://thenextweb.com/apps/2015/05/21/quick-test-shows-if-isps-are-secretly-throttling-your-internet-speeds/)

Answer (score 2):

Possibly, but if you were being throttled by your ISP I would expect the entire link to be capped, not individual sessions.  However, it shouldn't hurt to ask them if you are being throttled and why.

Before that I would check if there's something on your connection using up your bandwidth.  Some routers provide utilisation statistics per client IP.  I would check for that and see if you have a particular device (computer, tablet, smartphone, internet enabled HDTV, etc) maxing out your connection.

If you only have a single computer connected to your network check which processes might be using the most traffic.  Some operating systems support it out of the box, otherwise you can use the netstat command or look for other 3rd party utilities that can check.  [This previous discussion might help.](https://superuser.com/questions/50014/how-to-determine-what-app-is-generating-network-traffic)

Another thing you can check is if QoS is enabled on your router and whether its configured properly.